# ADO pipeline doesn't trigger when other pipeline(s) are completed

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, cicd

```
trigger: none # add this trigger value to none | This means that this pipeline will only be triggered after completion of below pipelines. Not after commit
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: example-name-1 # any arbitrary name
    source: example-name-1    # name of the pipeline shown on azure UI portal
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - develop  # name of branch on which pipeline need to trigger
        - qa
        - master  
  - pipeline: example-name-2 # any arbitrary name
    source: example-name-2    # name of the pipeline shown on azure UI portal
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - develop  # name of branch on which pipeline need to trigger
        - qa
        - master
```

This yaml file is in an ADO project, Let's call it Pipeline A. The two other pipelines (B & C) are also running in the same ADO project. However, the code for pipelines B & C that should trigger pipeline A are stored are in GitHub.

So the pipelines B&C get triggered whenever a developer commits the code to the GitHub repo. These pipelines run in the same ADO project and are completed. But now pipeline A is not triggered.

What am I missing?